# Is it acceptable to verbalize inshallah when messaging about intended acts?

Tags: allah

This morning I messaged a friend "I'll be there" but I didn't write "inshallah" (as per [Qur'an 18:23-24](https://quran.com/18:23)) in the text, instead verbalizing it (i.e., saying "inshallah", instead of including it in the text).  I'm worried this is incorrect, and I'd like to correct this behaviour in the future.

**Question**: Is it acceptable to verbalize inshallah when messaging about intended acts?

I found this as part of an online fatwa:

> Finally, I would advise that while sending messages through SMS or email, one should always write in sha' Allah (ان شاء الله). -- Abu al-Fadl Muhammad Nau'man Shiraz al-Qadiri al-'Iraqi ([link](http://www.alahazrat.net/islam/correct-way-of-writing-in-sha-allah-(english).php))

But the context from that fatwa is not this particular question.  As such, it's unclear whether the author is intending to only say "using SMS, etc., does not exempt you from saying inshallah".  (And it's an isolated opinion on some website, without referencing the Qur'an or Sunnah.)

Comment: A relevant question that might be good to ask is; "is it obligatory to say inshallah on every intended act?"

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there is anything wrong with saying inshaAllah rather than writing it. The point is remembering that the future is in Allah's hands, and that nothing takes place unless He wills it.

Writing inshaAllah has the benefit of reminding the recipient as well. But then, many people read, write, and say inshaAllah as a habit, without thinking about the deeper meaning behind it; so *Actions are by intentions*, it's the thought that matters most.